# jQuery single submit sends two requests to the same url

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have to the following html form:

```
<form method="post" action="create_user" autocomplete="off" class="user_create_form">
<table class="table table-bordered user">
    <tr>
        <td class="w20"> Pick Role/Module </td>
        <td> <?php echo($db->getRolesCmb()); ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Pick Employee </td>
        <td> <?php echo($db->getEmployeeCmb()); ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Choose User ID </td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" placeholder="Choose User Id for Login"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Choose User Password </td>
        <td> <input type="password" name="userkey" id="userkey" placeholder="Choose User Password for Login"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Confirm User Password </td>
        <td> <input type="password" name="cuserkey" id="cuserkey" placeholder="Confirm User Password for Login"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Login Status </td>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="user_status" id="user_status1" value="1" checked> Enabled
         <input type="radio" name="user_status" id="user_status2" value="0"> Disabled
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
    <button name="btnSave" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success">Create User</button>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span id="msg"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</form>
```

I have to following .js file attached to this page which validate and submit this form with the following method:

```
          // JavaScript Document
          "use strict";
          $(document).ready(function(e) {
              $(".user_create_form").bind("submit",function(event){
                  event.preventDefault();
                  if($("#roles").val() == ""){
                      $("#roles").focus();
                      $("#msg").html('Please select Module for User').addClass("text-danger");
                      return false;
                      }
                  else if($("#emp_sno").val() == ""){
                      $("#emp_sno").focus();
                      $("#msg").html('Please select employee for the login').addClass("text-danger");
                      return false;
                      }
                  else if($.trim($("#userid").val()) == ""){
                      $("#userid").focus();
                      $("#msg").html('User id is required here').addClass("text-danger");
                      return false;
                      }
                  else if($.trim($("#userkey").val()) == ""){
                      $("#userkey").focus();
                      $("#msg").html('Please choose password for user login').addClass("text-danger");
                      return false;
                      }
                  else if($.trim($("#cuserkey").val()) == ""){
                      $("#cuserkey").focus();
                      $("#msg").html('Password confirmation required').addClass("text-danger");
                      return false;
                      }
                  else if($.trim($("#userkey").val()) != $.trim($("#cuserkey").val())){
                      $("#cuserkey").focus();
                      $("#msg").html('Password does not match').addClass("text-danger");
                      return false;
                      }
                  else{
                      // save login information to database
                      $.ajax({
                          url: 'myPageUrl.php',
                          data: new FormData(this),
                          type:"POST",
                          cache:false,
                          contentType:false,
                          processData:false,
                          success: function(txt){
                              $("#msg").html(txt).removeClass('text-danger');
                              },
                          error: function(xhr){
                              $("#msg").html(xhr);
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  });
          });
```

The problem is that when I check the network process on net tab on Firefox "Firebug" extension it shows two requests to the same url with one single click.

Now I am confused about what I am doing wrong? Why does it send two requests to the same URL with one single click?

Comment: you are performing a select on a class, can you first verify that after your page has rendered, you only have one <form class="user_create_form"> on page? Maybe running $(".user_create_form").length in your console would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an on handler instead of bind, and unbind it so it only fires once.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#user_create_form').unbind().on('submit', function() { ... })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

add `onsubmit="return false"` in form tag like this

`<form method="post" action="create_user" autocomplete="off" class="user_create_form">`

I guess it will work. Your form tag do its work and js do its work . SO there might be a collision

Comment: i tested your solution but still it sends two parallel requests to the same url.